# What is DOMXPath using? DOM or XPath?

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath

I'm a bit confused about the name "DOMXPath".
To work with it I have to use XPath functions and not DOM.

But to initiate it I have first to create a

```
$dom = new DOMDocument()
```

and then

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom)
```

So does this mean that XPath depends on DOM?
I'm sorry for this confusion but I'm actually writing on my Dissertation and this name "DOMXPath" confused me so much.
So I'm even not sure if I should explain in my introduction what is DOM or should I explain XPath?

Answer (score 2):

DOM and XPath are different concepts. DOM (Document Object Model) is a representation of a document or document fragment consisting of XML nodes arranged as a tree.

XPath is a syntax for expressing a navigation through a DOM to locate one or more nodes.

The name DOMXPath in PHP is somewhat redundant. They could have just called it XPath.

Comment: But to be concrete I Need first a DOM to Access the nodes with XPath. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

The DOMXpath class is part of PHPs DOM extension. Like the other classes in the extension it uses a "DOM" prefix. It is not a special kind of Xpath, but just the Xpath class from PHPs DOM extension.

[DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/) and [Xpath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) are W3C standards. The DOM-API and the Xpath syntax are available in many languages. Here are differences and optimizations depending on the language/the implementation, but the basics are the same.

Comment: Ok, thank you. When I understand this is XPath neutral and so the syntax is nearly equal in every language.